# pip error: "The term 'pip' is not recognized..."

Tags: python, pip

I saw in my terminal the following error after I tried to run "pip list":

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip list
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Use `py -3 -m pip` instead

Answer (score -1):

Try typing pip3 instead of pip.
Make sure pip is actaully installed. If youre on linux you can install pip3 using most package managers. It also comes with every Python installation.

Comment: That error is coming from Powershell on Windows.